# A dictionary with a unique possible value for each key?

Tags: python, dictionary, data-structures, language-agnostic

I need to create a map from twitter status IDs to their author ID.
Obviously, each status has exactly one author.

I expected [Python collections](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html) to have something like `uniqdict` class for which `d[key] = value` will raise an exception if the `key` already has a value **different** from `value`:

```
class uniqdict(dict):
    def __setitem__(self,key,value):
        try:
            old = super(uniqdict,self).__getitem__(key)
            if old != value:
                raise ValueError(self.__class__.__name__,key,old,value)
        except KeyError:
            super(uniqdict,self).__setitem__(key,value)
```

### Q: Is there a *standard name* for this kind of dictionary/map/hash table?

Comment: I can't think of anything that's built-in. You'll probably have to roll your own.

Comment: Short answer: no, but it would be nice to have. Consider putting in a request to Guido. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a duplicate of [Write-once dictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21601593/write-once-dictionary)

Anyway, I think write-once dictionary is the name you're looking for

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar requirement recently, where I needed to merge two dicts but it was an error if they had any keys in common.

I don't think there is a standard name, so let me propose one: a *no-overwrite dictionary*.

Or perhaps *single-update keys dictionary*, but that's a bit ugly.

(The simpler alternative *single-update dictionary* seems too misleading.)